# How can I prevent the application.hbs from appearing in its routes

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, ember-router

I have an Ember application that has several routes. I however, don't want the content from `application.hbs` appearing in its routes. I have tried:

```
renderTemplate: function () {
  this.render("another_outlet");
}
```

But it shows content from `another_outlet.hbs` alongside content from `application.hbs` in the route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont. The sole purpose of the `application.hbs` is to have a place to put something that should always be visible.

If you want something only on the root of you app (`/`) then you should put it into the `index.hbs`.